# Django redirecting to a wrong url

Tags: python, django, web

when i click submit on my form it goes to ../register/register/ where as my expectation is that it should go to ../register

This is my main project urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('participants/', include('participants.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is my application urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name="register")
]
```

This is my views function

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        # email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['pass']
        print(username, password)
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        user.save()
        return redirect('register')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Comment: What have you set the form tag's `action` attribute to in your template?

Comment: show me your urls.py full file and template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding namespaces to your urls

Main project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('participants/', include('participants.urls', namespace='participants')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Application urls.py

```
app_name = 'participants'
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name="register")
]
```

View

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    ...
    return redirect('participants:register')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can install `django-extensions` and run `manage.py show_urls` to find out what urls you have and also try `reverse('register')` to check where it point to.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return redirect('/register')
```

instead of

```
return redirect('register')
```

You would need the slash('/') at the front to let Django know that it's referencing the root of the named URL that is after the Hostname.

Without the slash, it'll just append to the current named URL